# Expecting Log Messages fails when akka.testkit.TestEventListener moved to different resource

Tags: akka, config, typesafe-stack

This is really weird issue.

My `application.conf` looks like

```
akka {
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
  loglevel = "INFO"
  loggers = [akka.testkit.TestEventListener]
}

ec {
  name = "myApp"
}

tenant {
  assetsLocation: /Users
}

monitoring {
  tenant.disk.schedule.seconds: 2
  tenant.disk.threshold.percent: 80
}
```

and then I write my test as

```
@Test
  public void testActorForNonExistentLocation() throws Exception {
    final Map<String, String> configValues = Collections.singletonMap("tenant.assetsLocation",
                                                                      "/non/existentLocation");
    final Config config = mergeConfig(configValues);


    new JavaTestKit(system) {{
      assertEquals("system", system.name());

      final Props props = TenantMonitorActor.props(config);
      final ActorRef supervisor = system.actorOf(props, "supervisor");
      new EventFilter<Void>(DiskException.class) {

        @Override
        protected Void run() {
          supervisor.tell(new TenantMonitorMessage(), supervisor);
          return null;
        }
      }.from("akka://system/user/supervisor/diskMonitor").occurrences(1).exec();

    }};
  }
```

and everything works. Then I write a new `test.monitoring.conf` as

```
include "application.conf"

akka {
  loggers = [akka.testkit.TestEventListener]
}
```

and remove the line `loggers = [akka.testkit.TestEventListener]` from `application.conf`.

I see test failure as

```
INFO] [05/02/2015 17:20:11.301] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://system/user/supervisor] Scheduling Disk Monitor
[INFO] [05/02/2015 17:20:11.304] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://system/user/supervisor/diskMonitor] disk: /non/existentLocation, total space: 0, usable space: 0
[ERROR] [05/02/2015 17:20:11.309] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://system/user/supervisor/diskMonitor] /non/existentLocation does not exists
com.self.monitoring.tenant.exception.DiskException: /non/existentLocation does not exists
    at com.self.monitoring.tenant.DiskMonitorActor.validateAssetsDirectory(DiskMonitorActor.java:55)
    at com.self.monitoring.tenant.DiskMonitorActor.onReceive(DiskMonitorActor.java:42)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:167)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:97)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:254)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:221)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

[INFO] [05/02/2015 17:20:13.308] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://system/user/supervisor/diskMonitor] Message [com.self.monitoring.tenant.message.DiskMonitorMessage] from Actor[akka://system/deadLetters] to Actor[akka://system/user/supervisor/diskMonitor#935599425] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

java.lang.AssertionError: Timeout (3000 milliseconds) waiting for 1 messages on ErrorFilter(class com.self.monitoring.tenant.exception.DiskException,Some(akka://system/user/supervisor/diskMonitor),Left(),false)
    at akka.testkit.EventFilter.intercept(TestEventListener.scala:104)
    at akka.testkit.JavaTestKit$EventFilter.exec(JavaTestKit.java:626)
    at com.self.monitoring.tenant.TestTenantMonitorActor$2.<init>(TestTenantMonitorActor.java:83)
    at com.self.monitoring.tenant.TestTenantMonitorActor.testActorForNonExistentLocation(TestTenantMonitorActor.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I also inspected if `akka.testkit.TestEventListener` is missing, but its there

```
 @Test
  public void testActorForNonExistentLocation() throws Exception {
    final Map<String, String> configValues = Collections.singletonMap("tenant.assetsLocation",
                                                                      "/non/existentLocation");
    final Config config = mergeConfig(configValues);
    System.out.println(config.getList("akka.loggers"));
.....
```

and I see that its present.

```
SimpleConfigList(["akka.testkit.TestEventListener"])
[INFO] [05/02/2015 17:22:09.703] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://system/user/supervisor] Scheduling Disk Monitor
[INFO] [05/02/2015 17:22:09.705] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://system/user/supervisor/diskMonitor] disk: /non/existentLocation, total space: 0, usable space: 0
[ERROR] [05/02/2015 17:22:09.709] [system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://system/user/supervisor/diskMonitor] /non/existentLocation does not exists
```

What is the issue here?